# Interpolate continuous curve from noisy data

Tags: python, image-processing, interpolation, curve-fitting

I am trying to estimate/interpolate a curve from noisy data like the circle in the example. My data consists of more than circles but this should be a good starting point for solving the other structures as well.

I have a noisy binary image and I am trying to fit a continuous curve/skeleton to it (each pixel has 2 neighbours, except maybe start and end pixel, if the shape is not circular).
I had some success fitting the x,y coordinates separately, using the distance to a starting point as x values and the coordinates as y value and then interpolating distances in small steps. Then I checked if the coordinates were all connected. In some extreme cases the new interpolated points are not connected and I have to use smaller steps for the interpolation. This often also leads to pixels with more than 2 neighbours and other weird artifacts.

Is there an easier way to fit these values to a curve and to get a continuous curve as a result?

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import draw
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
image = np.zeros((200,200), dtype=np.uint8)

coords = np.array(draw.circle_perimeter(100,100,50))

noise = np.random.normal(0,2,coords.shape).astype(np.int64)

coords += noise
image[coords[0], coords[1]] = 1

plt.imshow(image, cmap="gray")

plt.show()
```

[image: noisy_circle]

Answer (score 3):

To fit data, you need a model. There are any number of ways of fitting a circle. The one I've had the most success with is Ian Coope's linearized solution. The paper is available here: https://ir.canterbury.ac.nz/handle/10092/11104

I've made a python implementation of it in a linearized fitting library called [scikit-guess](https://scikit-guess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The function is [`skg.nsphere_fit`](https://scikit-guess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/skg.nsphere_fit.html). Given your `(2, n)` array `coords`, you would use it like this:

```
from skg import nsphere_fit

radius, center = nsphere_fit(coords, axis=0)
```

To plot over your image, you can use [`matplotlib.patches.Circle`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Circle.html):

```
from matplotlib.patches import Circle

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
ax.add_patch(Circle(center[::-1], radius, edgecolor='red', facecolor='none'))
```

You need to reverse `center` because your input coordinates are `(row, col)`, while `Circle` expects `(x, y)`, which is `(col, row)`.

[image]

To fit a different model, you would need a different method. For arbitrary models, you might want to look into [`scipy.optimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) and [`lmfit`](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/).

Answer (score 1):

Fitting a circle to noisy data is very simple :

[image]

This method comes from https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14819165/Regressions-coniques-quadriques-circulaire-spherique